# Spatial adjustment of vector data in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, vector, affine-transformation

Is there any plugin or code reference available to spatially adjust vector data based on points selection like in the Spatial Adjustment tool of ArcGIS Desktop?

I am trying to develop spatial adjustment tool plugin in QGIS.

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at the [Vector Bender](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/VectorBender/) plugin.
It allows you to perform Translation, Rotation and Transformation of vector layer and nodes.

Here's a video that gives you an example of how it works
https://vimeo.com/96142479